# What happens if a target for removal becomes ineligible after a card has been cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When you have a card like [Complete Disregard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Complete%20Disregard) which reads "Exile Target Creature with power 3 or less", as I understand it, it becomes untargetable if the opponent's creature power increases thanks to a pump spell like [Brute Strength](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brute%20Strength).

**But what if the Disregard is already on the stack and targeting; and they respond with Brute Strength?** I'm pretty sure (and my opponent with Brute Strength was *certain*) that it won't exile the creature, but I don't know which rule states this, and there's no gatherer ruling on the spell.

Comment: Small note; you say "it won't kill the creature", but for clarity, the creature won't "die" either way; if the spell resolves than the creature will be exiled, which is different from dying.

Comment: Good point, was using kill in the vernacular (I mean, if whatever they do to you leaves you alive that seems bad), fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MTG: Making a card ineligible as a target once a card has been cast](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29050/mtg-making-a-card-ineligible-as-a-target-once-a-card-has-been-cast)

Comment: I think that other question should be closed as a duplicate of this one... this one came first.

Comment: I vote for this question to be closed, because the other one is worded more universally. Also the best answer is more concise there, while still carrying (more or less) the same information.

Comment: What @tsuma said. As the writer of this question, I think the other question is more general, and thus going to there from here would be better than the other way around. As far as I know, closing doesn't have any negative effects except people would have to answer on the other question?

Comment: Thank you, @deworde, for being more concerned about which dupe target is best than your own question. I think this question is more well written. I think the other question has a more general title. It could go either way honestly.

Comment: @Rainbolt Certainly if mine gets picked I'm shamelessly nicking his title...

Comment: The question that this is being marked for as a duplicate of is already closed as a duplicate of this question so until that is resolved this should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoeW It is impossible to close two questions as duplicates of each other. If you try to do it anyway, you'll see a message like [this](http://i.imgur.com/8LCajAW.png). The close votes on this question will decay at a rate of 1 vote every two days, so long as nobody casts any other types of close votes.

Comment: @Rainbolt That should have prevented it from entering the queue in the first place and not depend on code to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**At resolution, Complete Disregard will instead leave the stack and be put into its owner's graveyard without doing anything, because all its targets have become illegal.**

Targeting spells and abilities check the legality of their targets twice; once as you put them on the stack, and again just before they resolve. If all their targets have become illegal at the time of the second check, it doesn't resolve at all.

If some, but not all, of its targets become illegal before the second check, the spell or ability resolves but does not affect or obtain information about those illegal targets.

> 608. Resolving Spells and Abilities
>
> 608.2b **If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal.** A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process. **If all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal, the spell or ability doesn’t resolve.** It’s removed from the stack and, if it’s a spell, put into its owner’s graveyard. Otherwise, the spell or ability will resolve normally. Illegal targets, if any, won’t be affected by parts of a resolving spell’s effect for which they’re illegal. Other parts of the effect for which those targets are not illegal may still affect them. If the spell or ability creates any continuous effects that affect game rules (see rule 613.11), those effects don’t apply to illegal targets. If part of the effect requires information about an illegal target, it fails to determine any such information. Any part of the effect that requires that information won’t happen.

Comment: I'm sure I remember an exception to this or rather a thing that behaves differently. Something like "when X enters the battlefield draw a card if you control 2 creatures"

Comment: @deworde your example does not contain the word "target", so that is unrelated to your question and my answer, not an exception.