# What happens if a target becomes ineligible after a card has been cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I cast
[Strangling Soot](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368521) on [Llanowar Elves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393970).

Before this resolves, my opponent casts [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205224) on the Llanowar Elves.

Giant Growth resolves, making the Llanowar Elves a 4/4. When the Strangling Soot resolves, is it able to destroy the Llanowar elves, or does it do nothing because Llanowar elves no longer has a toughness of 3 or less?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strangling Soot has an illegal target (only one) as it resolves and therefore fizzles (is countered by game rules due to all targets being invalid).

When you cast a spell with targets, you check the validity of all targets as it is *cast*. If any targets are invalid, the spell is "undone" and goes back to where it started. As the spell *resolves*, it again checks if the targets are valid. If any are valid, it resolves as much as it can; if not, it fizzles.

> **608.2b** If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. .......

Comment: As a point of clarification, the spell only fizzles during the second target check if *all* of the targets are illegal.

Comment: So if I had cast a card that destroys 2 creatures, then my opponent unsummons once of the targets, the remaining creature still gets destroyed?

Comment: @tarun713 correct

Comment: @tarun713 You have to be exact in your wording. If the spell would destroy 2 *target* creatures, and one becomes illegal, it will still destroy the other. If both become illegal, it will be countered. If the spell does not target the creatures, and both get unsommoned, the spell would still resolve and do whatever else it might do.

Comment: Differentiating between some of the targets of a spell becoming illegal and all targets of a spell becoming illegal, and how it affects the resolution of the spell, is beneficial. However, to avoid conflating the two, consider referencing a spell that can target more than one permanent (Consign to Dust, etc). Strangling Soot will always target one creature, so will be fizzle if that creature becomes an illegal target.

Comment: @JonTheMon To be clear for future readers, I'd suggest explaining in the answer that "fizzles" means being countered due to all targets becoming invalid. Not that it's a bad answer as is, of course.